# Voter classes in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, voting

I'm taking over someone's code and I don't understand something about the voting.

Here is the PhotosController class:

```
class PhotosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/dashboard/photos/{id}/view", name="dashboard_photos_view")
     * @Security("is_granted('view.photo', photo)")
     * @param Photo $photo
     * @param PhotoRepository $photoRepository
     */
    public function index(Photo $photo, PhotoRepository $photoRepository)
    {
        $obj = $photoRepository->getFileObjectFromS3($photo);
        header("Content-Type: {$obj['ContentType']}");
        echo $obj['Body'];
        exit;
    }
```

Here is the voter class:

```
class PhotoVoter extends Voter
{
    const VIEW        = 'view.photo';
    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!$subject instanceof Photo) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::VIEW))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface    $token)
    {
        return $subject->getUser()->getId() === $token->getUser()->getId();
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the

> , photo

is for in the PhotosController class.  And  in PhpStorm I get "cannot find declaration" when I try to go to the "is_granted" declaration.

Comment: There is no special significance to .photo.  The attribute could be any string.  Using just 'view' is perhaps a bit more normal.  But again, it could be anything.  Since you are supporting  legacy app then you might want to take a look at any other custom voters and just follow whatever standards the original developer had.

Comment: Hi Cerad, it's not the . (dot) photo I'm confused about, it's the , (comma) photo right after 'view.photo'.  I don't understand what it's use is.

Comment: It basically ends up calling the AuthorizationChecker::isGranted('view.photo',$photo) method which eventually ends up calling the PhotoVoter instance.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html.  Never did care for annotations myself.

Comment: So it capitalizes the first letter and changes "photo" to "Photo" and then looks for PhotoVoter?  Is that the process?

Comment: Shouldn't it say ", $photo" then instead of ", photo"?

Comment: Nope.  Look over the doc link I posted.  'photo' is the variable name.  You don't need a $ because, well, because you don't.  The magic of annotation.  The authorization checker has a list of all available voters.  It uses the Voter::supports method to determine which voters to actually use.

Comment: And while a bit off topic, if the code actually uses header and echo to generate a response then buckle up because you are in for a very rough ride indeed.

Comment: Ok I'll do that.  Thanks so much for your help Cerad.